# Comparing element of an arraylist in method for an if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, methods, compare

I have to create a peghole game program that will display the numbers 1 through 10 then prompt the user to choose a number to set to 0. The 1-10 are all stored in an arraylist and if the user tries to make an element that was already set to 0 by them, set to 0 again then an if statement will display the message "Peghole is already filled!". How do I compare the value of the element the user picked to 0? I'm trying to accomplish this in the method peg_hole.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PegBoardGame {

public static ArrayList create_pegboard(){
    //for loop and add method to holes 1-10
    for(){

    }
}

public static void print_pegboard(ArrayList pegboard) {
    //print results from array 1-10 or final result
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(pegboard);
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
}

public static Integer peg_hole(ArrayList pegboard){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    //variable for user input
    int holetofillInt;
    int checkInt;
    //prompt for input
    System.out.println("Select a peghole 1-10 to fill");
    holetofillInt = in.nextInt();
    //if peg chosen by user is already 0 then print error message
    checkInt = pegboard[holetofillInt];
    if(  ){ 
        System.out.println("Peghole is already filled!");
    }
    else{
        //set selected hole to 0
        pegboard.set(holetofillInt,0);
        return holetofillInt;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    //create array list with peghole numbers
    ArrayList<Integer> pegboard = create_pegboard();
    //print the pegboard unchanged
    print_pegboard(pegboard);
    //construct array list up to 10
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        //see if they want to change and change what hole is peggged
         peg_hole(pegboard);
         //print changed peghole board
         print_pegboard(pegboard);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: try `pegboard.get(holetofillInt);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your `if` condition, do `pegboard.get(holetofillInt).equals(0)`.

There isn't really a need for the integer `checkInt`.

Answer (score 2):

With `ArrayList` you need to use the structure `list.get(index)` rather than `list[index]`.

```
public static Integer peg_hole(ArrayList pegboard){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    //variable for user input
    int holetofillInt;
    int checkInt;
    //prompt for input
    System.out.println("Select a peghole 1-10 to fill");
    holetofillInt = in.nextInt();
    //if peg chosen by user is already 0 then print error message
    checkInt = pegboard.get(holetofillInt);
    if(checkInt == 0){ 
        System.out.println("Peghole is already filled!");
    }
    else{
        //set selected hole to 0
        pegboard.set(holetofillInt,0);
        return holetofillInt;
    }
}
```